# Limit concurrent resource usage in a Java EE application

Tags: java, ejb, threadpool

There is a Java EE application where we have batches of jobs to process. Processing involves calling an external service that has a limitation so that we can send only N number of requests concurrently. This bottleneck has to be implemented in our application logic and I am wondering how could we achieve this in the best way. Fortunately clustering is not a requirement, so we can confine the problem to a single server instance.

- My first idea would be using an `ExecutorService` backed by a
  `ThreadPool` with N working threads so that the `ThreadPool` object
  would act as the regulator. Of course this is not an EE solution.
- My second idea would be somehow configuring such a `ThreadPool` in
  the container and using that, but I have not found any feature like
  this so far.
- The third idea is using a `Semaphore(N)` object in a `@Singleton`
  EJB.
- The fourth idea is somehow creating a limited pool of stateless
  session beans and putting the limited-resource access in those. As
  the bean number is managed by the container, the resource usage will
  be limited as well

(To clarify: a general solution would be the best, but it is known that we're running on Glassfish 3.1.1 and maybe later on JBoss 6.x)

Could you suggest me a good architecture for this problem and/or comment on my ideas to help my decision?

Comment: Other ideas are still welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use **Works**? Have a look [here](http://danielveselka.blogspot.it/2012/03/schedule-jobs-with-workmanager.html) for an overview of how to use Works in JBoss and Weblogic. I don't know about Glasshfish, I'll leave the research to you now ;)
In short, Works are EE compliant threads.

Comment: Thanks, tbh never heard about it. Started investigating.. :-)

Comment: As I see [JSR-237 http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=237] was withdrawn and [JSR-236 http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236] was put into finalization just yesterday.. :-)

Comment: I see, didn't know that "JCA WorkManager API is only appropriate for use within Resource Adapters". So I've been using some sort of workaround until now. :-O

Answer (score 1):

The canonical solution for concurrent message processing in Java EE is to use MDBs. You can limit the number of concurrently running tasks by limiting the MDB pool size.

- [Setting MDB Pool Size in Glassfish](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abebw.html#abedk)
- [JBoss 7 EJB3 Subsystem Configuration Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB3+subsystem+configuration+guide)